# Show date with custom month name, php

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Im new to php and not sure how to operate with the string or date. I have custom month names, stored in array:

```
$months = ['1' => 'my Jan', '2'=>'my Feb', '3'=>'my Mar', '4'=>'my Apr', //etc.];
```

I'd like to show the date with these month names, currently I show:

```
date_format(new DateTime($route->start_date), 'd F Y')
```

which gives `01 January 2016`

I need to get `01 my Jan 2016`.

Thanks

Comment: from where `$route->start_date`? is coming can you show that?

Comment: it is from `Active Record`, it has type `date` in database.

Comment: like this??? 01 my Jan, 02 my Feb .....

Comment: or like this??? 18 my Jan, 18 my Feb?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help.

```
<?php
$months = ['1' => 'my Jan', '2'=>'my Feb', '3'=>'my Mar', '4'=>'my Apr'];
$date = new DateTime($route->start_date);
echo '<br>'.$date->format('d').' '.$months[$date->format('n')].' '.$date->format('Y');

?>
```

Comment: You should not put such logic in views, because it violates MVC and DRY.

Comment: in my case, it is in controller, so works fine, thanks